# Two parallel arrows crossing over in Tikz-CD

Tags: tikz-cd

In a Tikz commutative diagram, I would like to draw two parallel arrows that cross over. Something like this:

```
A x B

|   |
|   |
 \ /
  X  f
 / \
|   |
V   V

C x D
```

(of course I would prefer the arrows to bend smoothly rather than have sharp corners).

(Here f is a map from the product A x B to the product C x D, and I want to visually suggest the fact this if f sends say a pair (a, b) to a pair (c, d), then c depends only on b and not on a, and d depends only on a and not on b.)

Does anyone know a simple way to do this? If it is impossible in Tikz-CD, maybe it is possible with another package?

Bonus points if it is possible to adjust the separation between the two arrows.

Comment: Not quite clear… Could you  post a hand-made sketch of what you'd like to obtain?

Comment: Here is an ASCII-art picture that hopefully makes it clear what I would like to get.

Comment: The entries in the diagram are named so it should not be a problem to make what Zarko did. There are some examples of this at the end of the manual for tikz-cd (not at a pc, so cannot test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do this frequently, you'll want a tikz style for it. Here's a style which you can add to a tikz-cd arrow to make it show up as a crossover:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
  crossover/.style = {
    decorate, 
    decoration={show path construction, lineto code={
      \coordinate (crossovertikzinputsegmentfirst) at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst);
      \coordinate (crossovertikzinputsegmentlast) at (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{crossovertikzinputsegmentfirst}{center}}
                                {\pgfpointanchor{crossovertikzinputsegmentlast}{center}}
      \let\ang\pgfmathresult
      \path ([shift=(90+\ang:#1)] \tikzinputsegmentfirst) edge[out=\ang, in=180+\ang] ([shift=(-90+\ang:#1)] \tikzinputsegmentlast)
            ([shift=(-90+\ang:#1)] \tikzinputsegmentfirst) edge[out=\ang, in=180+\ang] ([shift=(90+\ang:#1)] \tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
    commutative diagrams/labels={inner sep=#1},
  },
  crossover/.default=.8ex,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \times B \arrow[crossover=2ex]{d}{f} \arrow[crossover]{r}{g} & F\\
C \times D 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The optional argument is (half) the distance between the arrows.

[image: crossovers]

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

This is pure TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, calc, chains, positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 24mm and 0mm,
  start chain = A going right,
  line/.style = {line width=1mm, draw=gray, -Stealth[bend]}
                        ]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style = {minimum size= 7mm, outer sep=0pt, 
                                   font=\Large, on chain=A}]
\node   {$A$};              % <-- name: A-1
\node   {$\times$};
\node   {$B$};
%
\node[below=of A-1] {$C$};  % <-- name: A-4
\node   {$\times$};
\node   {$D$};
\end{scope} 
\coordinate[label={[xshift=1mm]right:$f$}] (x) at ($(A-2)!0.4!(A-5)$);
\draw[line] (A-1) to [out=-90, in=135] (x) to [out=- 45, in=90] (A-6); 
\draw[line] (A-3) to [out=-90, in= 45] (x) to [out=-135, in=90] (A-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have something more in line with the standard `tikz-cd` arrows?

Comment: @egreg, maybe it is possible. I'm not familiar with this TikZz derivative, so I consider "maybe it is possible with another package" part of OP question ...

Comment: Thank you. I'll take this if there is nothing else, but a way to do it in some higher-level package would be really nice. What I gave here is a MWE, but the complete diagram I want to draw is slightly more complex and adjusting everything by hand will be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I finally did. The code has a couple of issues:

- for some reason the label disappeared when I added the "to path" option, so I drew an invisible (white) arrow in order to print the label;
- it would probably abstract away the magical number "1ex" into a variable defined once and for all (but I do not know how to do this in TikZ);

but it works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
A \times B
  \arrow[white]{dd}{{\color{black} \hspace{1ex} f}}
  \arrow[rounded corners, to path =
      {([xshift=-1ex]\tikztostart.south)
    -- ([xshift=-1ex, yshift=1ex]$(\tikztostart.south)!.5!(\tikztotarget.north)$)
    -- ([xshift=1ex, yshift=-1ex]$(\tikztostart.south)!.5!(\tikztotarget.north)$)
    -- ([xshift=1ex]\tikztotarget.north)}]{dd}
  \arrow[rounded corners, to path =
      {([xshift=1ex]\tikztostart.south)
    -- ([xshift=1ex, yshift=1ex]$(\tikztostart.south)!.5!(\tikztotarget.north)$)
    -- ([xshift=-1ex, yshift=-1ex]$(\tikztostart.south)!.5!(\tikztotarget.north)$)
    -- ([xshift=-1ex]\tikztotarget.north)}]{dd}\\
\\
C \times D
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```